# Android | How to dismiss the previous dilogue before displaying next dilogue?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have multiple dilogue boxes for different different conditions. when I a dilogue is displayed for one condition and then I try to display another one for another condition. It overlaps the previous one.

**Specific Scenario**

I have two dialogues. One for when wifi is not active. Another one is when wifi is active. Suppose When I launched an app wifi was not active. So, it displayed a dilogue. Then I turned on wifi. It displayed another dilogue. But, It overlapped previous one. In below screenshot it is clearly visible by looking at the shadow of dilogue box. Left one is when wifi is on. And then I turned off the wifi and turned on again. And this overlapping happened.

**ScreenShots[image: Screenshot]**

**Java code**

```
 private BroadcastReceiver wifiStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int wifiStateExtra = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,
                    WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
            switch (wifiStateExtra) {


                case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
                    //WIFI ENABLED

                    {
                    info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                    if (!info.getSSID().trim().equals(ssid)) {
                        title = "Connect to Devil";
                        msg = "In order to work with system you need to be connected with Devil";

                        builder.setTitle(title);
                        builder.setMessage(msg);
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> startActivity(WiFiIntent));
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Close App", ((dialog, which) -> finishAffinity()));
                        alertDialog = builder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();
                        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

                    }

                    break;
                }


                case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
                    //WIFI DISABLED
                {
                    title = "Enable WiFi";
                    msg = "Please enable wifi and connect to Devil";
                    builder.setTitle(title);
                    builder.setMessage(msg);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> startActivity(WiFiIntent));
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Close App", ((dialog, which) -> finishAffinity()));
                    alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `cancel` before reassigning `alertDialog`:

```
...
alertDialog.cancel(); // add this line
alertDialog = builder.create();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to dismiss the previous the shown dialog before showing the next one.

please check this code and it is working fine as per your requirement

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MaterialAlertDialogBuilder materialDialog;
    private AlertDialog dialog;
    private String title;
    private String msg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        materialDialog = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        registerReceiver(wifiStateReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(wifiStateReceiver);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver wifiStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int wifiStateExtra = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);

            switch (wifiStateExtra) {

                case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
                    title = "Connected";
                    msg = "Wifi Enabled.";
                    materialDialog.setPositiveButton("ok", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }).setNegativeButton("close", (dialogInterface, i) -> {                    
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        showToast(msg);
                    });

                    break;
                case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
                    title = "disconnected";
                    msg = "Wifi Disabled.";
                    materialDialog.setPositiveButton("ok", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }).setNegativeButton("close", (dialogInterface, i) -> {                       
                      dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        showToast(msg);
                    });
                    break;
            }

            if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            dialog = materialDialog.setTitle(title).setMessage(msg).create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    };

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is giving the blinking effect to dialog

Comment: @Anirudhdhsinh Jadeja this is nothing related to blinking, because when dialog is shown it makes an overlay over the screen so instead of dialog we can use a snack bar to removing the blinking behaviour