# How do i get a alert dialog when internet is off

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
Future checkConnectivity (BuildContext context) async {
  try {
    final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
    if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
      print(result[0]);
    }
  } on SocketException catch (_) {
    //error alert dialog
  }
}
```

When internet is off i want to show a alert dialog to the user that there is no internet.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67313300/android-how-to-dismiss-the-previous-dilogue-before-displaying-next-dilogue/67314421#67314421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity

and do something like this:

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

...

@override
initState() {
  super.initState();

  subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
    if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      showDialog(...);
    }
  });
}

// Be sure to cancel subscription after you are done
@override
dispose() {
  super.dispose();

  subscription.cancel();
}
```